# Change option values of select 2 if select 1 has a value with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I require a bit of jQuery to do the following:

A user can currently select Program and/or a region.

If a user selects Program AND a Region I require the option values of the region dropdown to change to "?region=1" and "?region=2"

```
<select class="program" id="program">
            <option value="program1.html">Program 1</option>
            <option value="program2.html">Program 2</option>
</select>

<select class="region" id="region">
            <option value="region1.html">Region 1</option>
            <option value="region2.html">Region2</option>
</select>
```

Greatly appreciate the assist.

My attempt at JQuery:

```
$('#program').on('change', function () { if($(this).val() !="0") { } else { // no option is selected } })
```

Comment: What have you tried so far in terms of the JQuery? Please supply some starting code

Answer (score 0):

You need to further extend the `change` event for `#program` and include a similar one for `#region`.

```js
var programSelected = null;
var regionSelected = null;

$('#program').on('change', function(element) {
            programSelected = $('#program option:selected').text();
      
      updateRegionOptions();
});

$('#region').on('change', function(element) {
      regionSelected = $('#region option:selected').text();
      updateRegionOptions();
});

function updateRegionOptions() {
    if(programSelected != null && regionSelected != null) {
        $('#region option').each(function() {
        var modifiedString = '?';           
         modifiedString += $(this).val().replace(/\d+/,'');
         modifiedString = modifiedString.replace('.html','');   
         modifiedString += '=';
         modifiedString += $(this).val().match(/\d+/);
        $(this).val(modifiedString);
      });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="program" id="program">
  <option value="" selected disabled>Select Program</option>
  <option value="program1.html">Program 1</option>
  <option value="program2.html">Program 2</option>
</select>

<select class="region" id="region">
<option value="" selected disabled>Select Region</option>
  <option value="region1.html">Region 1</option>
  <option value="region2.html">Region2</option>
</select>
```

**Explanation of the logic above:**

1. `on('change'` event for both `#region` and `#program`
2. Set the relevant variable `programSelected` or `regionSelected` depending on the `change` event
3. Run function `updateRegionOptions();`
4. If the variables `programSelected` and `regionSelected` both have a value
5. For each of the options in `#region`
6. Mutate the existing `value` to be of the form `"?region=1" and "?region=2"`
7. Update the `value` section of each of the `option` elements to have this value

The relevant [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/347bwgym/1/) for review.